# Ошибка telethon

Tags: telethon

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telespam.py", line 17, in <module>

  File "telespam.py", line 14, in send_msg
    entity=client.get_entity(destination_user_username)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 310, in get_entity
    result.append(await self._get_entity_from_string(x))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 524, in _get_entity_from_string
    result = await self(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 77, in _call
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 75135 seconds is required (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы слишком часто отправляли сообщения или взаимодействовали с сервером. **Вам выдан временный лимит(блокировка) на *75135 секунд***. **Подождите**, а после попробуйте **реже** отправлять сообщения. Рекомендую сменить аккаунт.